# Android LiveData - how to throttle results

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have a liveData set up that emits some integers. but i would like to throttle the emissions such that it only happens every 5 seconds. but after the first 5 seconds have passed then the throttling can be removed.

here i am observing a count like this:

```
count1.observe(this, new Observer() {
      @Override public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer i) {
        //Do something with "integer"
      }
    });
```

but i want onChanged() callback to be throttled such that its just called maximum of 2 times within the first 5 seconds.  After the first 5 seconds have passed i dont need the throttling anymore at all.  Im not sure how to do this as i dont see any options for livedata to handle streams. i tried Transformation but it only has map and switchMap.   how can this be done ?  `enter code here`

Comment: Live data is not designed for that as far as I know. What is feeding your `count`? That's the place you should be looking into. If it's Rx, very easy task.

Comment: If you're using coroutines, you can also use Flow for that task: https://proandroiddev.com/from-rxjava-to-kotlin-flow-throttling-ed1778847619

Comment: thanks Mariusz, great link.

Comment: Unless I'm forgetting something, there is nothing built into the Jetpack for this. The existing `Transformations` are implemented using `MediatorLiveData`, and you should be able to create your own `MediatorLiveData` that implements your rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's `MediatorLiveData` implementation that throttles using a `Handler` (in Kotlin since Java has a lot of boilerplate).

If source livedata updates too often result emission will be delayed:

```
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData

/**
 * LiveData throttling value emissions so they don't happen more often than [delayMs].
 */
class ThrottledLiveData<T>(source: LiveData<T>, delayMs: Long) : MediatorLiveData<T>() {
    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    var delayMs = delayMs
        private set

    private var isValueDelayed = false
    private var delayedValue: T? = null
    private var delayRunnable: Runnable? = null
        set(value) {
            field?.let { handler.removeCallbacks(it) }
            value?.let { handler.postDelayed(it, delayMs) }
            field = value
        }
    private val objDelayRunnable = Runnable { if (consumeDelayedValue()) startDelay() }

    init {
        addSource(source) { newValue ->
            if (delayRunnable == null) {
                value = newValue
                startDelay()
            } else {
                isValueDelayed = true
                delayedValue = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    /** Start throttling or modify the delay. If [newDelay] is `0` (default) reuse previous delay value. */
    fun startThrottling(newDelay: Long = 0L) {
        require(newDelay >= 0L)
        when {
            newDelay > 0 -> delayMs = newDelay
            delayMs < 0 -> delayMs *= -1
            delayMs > 0 -> return
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("newDelay cannot be zero if old delayMs is zero")
        }
    }

    /** Stop throttling, if [immediate] emit any pending value now. */
    fun stopThrottling(immediate: Boolean = false) {
        if (delayMs <= 0) return
        delayMs *= -1
        if (immediate) consumeDelayedValue()
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        consumeDelayedValue()
    }

    // start counting the delay or clear it if conditions are not met
    private fun startDelay() {
        delayRunnable = if (delayMs > 0 && hasActiveObservers()) objDelayRunnable else null
    }

    private fun consumeDelayedValue(): Boolean {
        delayRunnable = null
        return if (isValueDelayed) {
            value = delayedValue
            delayedValue = null
            isValueDelayed = false
            true
        } else false
    }
}
```

Use it by passing your source live data as first argument and observing it instead:

```
val throttledCount = ThrottledLiveData(count1, 2500L)  // maximum of one update per 2.5 sec
throttledCount.observe(this, Observer { i: Int ->
    //Do something with "integer"
})
```

If you want to stop throttling after 5 seconds just post a delayed runnable that will disable it:

```
val disableThrottle = Runnable { throttledCount.stopThrottling() }
throttledCount.handler.postDelayed(disableThrottle, 5000L)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use Interval operator of rxjava.

> Interval Operator create an Observable that emits a sequence of integers spaced by a given time interval. It is used when we want to do a task again and again after some interval.

example :

```
val disposable =
Observable.interval(0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .flatMap {
        return@flatMap Observable.create<String> { emitter ->
            Log.d("IntervalExample", "Create")
            emitter.onNext("MindOrks")
            emitter.onComplete()
        }
    }
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe {
        Log.d("IntervalExample", it)
    }
compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
```

Here the task will be done again and again after 2 seconds of interval.

One thing to notice: It will keep going on forever.

How to stop that?

There are two ways to stop. The following are the two ways to stop it.

1. Using the compositeDisposable.dispose()
2. Using `take(n)` operator like below

   ```
   Observable.interval(0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).take(5).flatMap {
   return@flatMap Observable.create<String> { emitter ->
       Log.d("IntervalExample", "Create")
       emitter.onNext("MindOrks")
       emitter.onComplete()
       }
   }
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe {
       Log.d("IntervalExample", it)
   }
   ```

As we have passed 5 as a parameter in the `take(5)`, the task will only be done 5 times with an interval of 2 seconds.

Comment: but i have a liveData,  how can i make this work with a liveData. i dont own the liveData , they are just giving me a liveData to work with. how can  i wrap it in these calls ?

Comment: you can use Periodic work manager with the live data, that will also help you to achieve it.